# AWS EC2 instance not rising above 60% CPU utilization

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cpu-usage

We have an AWS Scaling Group with several EC2 instances that will never go over 60% CPU utilization rate and we have no idea why. We have other servers with similar functions and builds that don't have the problem.

All of the instances are on a M4-large instance running a Rails app and handling Sidekiq just like most of our other servers. We tried to compare the important configs (nginx, puma, sidekiq, rails) of those utilizing the full CPU and this one that's not for ideas but we're still stumped. This ASG is running Kafka and the others don't but thats the only major difference.

I apologize in advance as I know its a very vague question, below is a copy of `htop`

```
$

  1  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                         50.3%]     Tasks: 40, 72 thr; 3 running
  2  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                               58.2%]     Load average: 1.99 1.54 0.91
  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                                                        1180/7984MB]     Uptime: 00:19:02
  Swp[                                                                                                                         0/0MB]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 1153 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S 104.  8.0 13:23.69 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 7821 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S 20.9  8.0  0:23.71 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 7337 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S 16.9  8.0  0:25.71 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
15548 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S 12.2  8.0  0:04.56 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 7351 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S 10.1  8.0  0:23.19 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1573 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S 10.1  8.0  0:39.57 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1578 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  9.5  8.0  0:38.50 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1570 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  4.1  8.0  0:41.56 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1579 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 R  4.1  8.0  0:39.75 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1390 ubuntu     20   0 1155M  177M  6888 S  3.4  2.2  0:41.17 puma: cluster worker 1: 1078 [company-cs]
 7455 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  3.4  8.0  0:24.58 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1333 ubuntu     20   0  622M 31324  2632 S  2.7  0.4  0:29.24 kafka_consumer-c=/home/ubuntu/company-cs/config/kafka.yml -d
 8491 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  2.0  8.0  0:20.92 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
13051 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  2.0  8.0  0:11.14 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1580 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  2.0  8.0  0:38.74 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1428 ubuntu     20   0  622M 31324  2632 S  2.0  0.4  0:06.85 kafka_consumer-c=/home/ubuntu/company-cs/config/kafka.yml -d
 1584 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  1.4  8.0  0:38.88 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1386 ubuntu     20   0 1220M  185M  6948 S  1.4  2.3  0:41.74 puma: cluster worker 0: 1078 [company-cs]
 7830 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  1.4  8.0  0:24.69 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1575 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  1.4  8.0  0:38.60 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1582 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  1.4  8.0  0:39.32 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
13166 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  1.4  8.0  0:10.51 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
15549 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  1.4  8.0  0:04.15 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1571 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  1.4  8.0  0:39.60 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
17297 ubuntu     20   0 1155M  177M  6888 S  1.4  2.2  0:00.36 puma: cluster worker 1: 1078 [company-cs]
17618 ubuntu     20   0 1155M  177M  6888 S  1.4  2.2  0:00.25 puma: cluster worker 1: 1078 [company-cs]
14791 ubuntu     20   0 1220M  185M  6948 S  1.4  2.3  0:01.75 puma: cluster worker 0: 1078 [company-cs]
 1567 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  0.7  8.0  0:41.17 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
15347 ubuntu     20   0 1155M  177M  6888 S  0.7  2.2  0:01.93 puma: cluster worker 1: 1078 [company-cs]
15348 ubuntu     20   0 1220M  185M  6948 S  0.7  2.3  0:01.37 puma: cluster worker 0: 1078 [company-cs]
 1431 www-data   20   0 86436  3368  1760 S  0.7  0.0  0:02.04 nginx: worker process
 1408 ubuntu     20   0  622M 31324  2632 S  0.7  0.4  0:06.92 kafka_consumer-c=/home/ubuntu/company-cs/config/kafka.yml -d
 1412 root       20   0 33936 26736  5012 S  0.0  0.3  0:12.75 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat
 1522 root       20   0 33936 26736  5012 S  0.0  0.3  0:02.33 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat
 1425 root       20   0 33936 26736  5012 S  0.0  0.3  0:01.21 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat
16111 ubuntu     20   0 1220M  185M  6948 S  0.0  2.3  0:00.85 puma: cluster worker 0: 1078 [company-cs]
17809 ubuntu     20   0 25852  3352  1448 R  0.0  0.0  0:00.09 htop
 1394 ubuntu     20   0  622M 31324  2632 S  0.0  0.4  0:06.94 kafka_consumer-c=/home/ubuntu/company-cs/config/kafka.yml -d
 1396 ubuntu     20   0  622M 31324  2632 S  0.0  0.4  0:07.73 kafka_consumer-c=/home/ubuntu/company-cs/config/kafka.yml -d
    1 root       20   0 33620  2896  1484 S  0.0  0.0  0:02.89 /sbin/init
 1424 root       20   0 33936 26736  5012 S  0.0  0.3  0:02.55 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat
 1523 root       20   0 33936 26736  5012 S  0.0  0.3  0:02.35 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat
 1295 ubuntu     20   0 1322M  634M  7732 S  0.0  8.0  0:00.18 sidekiq 4.2.9 company-cs [19 of 20 busy]
 1592 ubuntu     20   0 1220M  185M  6948 S  0.0  2.3  0:00.40 puma: cluster worker 0: 1078 [company-cs]
 1415 root       20   0 33936 26736  5012 S  0.0  0.3  0:01.67 /usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/filebeat -path.config /etc/filebeat -path.data /var/lib/filebeat -path.logs /var/log/filebeat
  421 root       20   0 19488   652   460 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.09 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
  427 root       20   0 50000  1964  1000 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.23 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
  549 root       20   0 15272   400   192 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
  597 root       20   0 10232  2412   116 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases eth0
  833 messagebu  20   0 39224  1216   848 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.02 dbus-daemon --system --fork
  886 root       20   0 43460  1764  1424 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
F1Help  F2Setup F3SearchF4FilterF5Tree  F6SortByF7Nice -F8Nice +F9Kill  F10Quit
```

---

*Update*

```
$ iostat -x
Linux 3.13.0-100-generic (ip-172-31-16-77)  11/27/2017  _x86_64_    (2 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          25.58    0.01    0.66    0.18    0.11   73.46

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.05     3.08    0.89    2.07    18.23   121.32    94.07     0.03   11.01    9.70   11.58   1.31   0.39
```

---

*Update 2*

[image: CPU utilization % for the problem ASG]

Comment: Vague answer to a vague question: if you can't saturate your CPU, then you must be saturating something else.  How's your disk I/O?  Is this server behind a load balancer with other instances that are only half its size?

Comment: Good theory the server is behind a load balancer but all of the other instances in its scaling group are the same size M4.large. What would be a good way to monitor disk IO on ubuntu?

Comment: `iostat -x 1`.  Also, you're saying this instance is one of several identical machines, but the others don't show the same behavior?  Some types of older instance classes (e.g. m1, iirc) had a (non)-issue where AWS would sometimes provision you on hardware more powerful than you were paying for and then "steal" the surplus capacity, which would show in `top` as `st` "stolen" CPU cycles. People incorrectly assumed this was oversubscription/noisy-neighbor (it wasn't).  I don't think that happens with m4, but maybe worth checking.

Comment: Kill a bad server, let auto scaling create another. Report back if it has a problem or not.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot we have one other set of servers on M4.larges too, but they routinely hit >80% and scale up no problem. For all of our 40 servers we have scaling policies set for 70% and they all function as planned, this is the only the server group that has a special scaling policy (>48%). I updated my question above with the `iostat -x` output. Also the stolen amount when I used `top` was at most `0.2 st` so I doubt its that.

Comment: @Tim we have scaling policies setup already so this config has probably been on 100+ servers over the last month. It has to be something to do with our code/config and not just a bad server.

Comment: If your scaling policy is 48% then it's not clear why a machine not exceeding 60% is a problem... you should be getting new machines started when the load increases, relieving the demand from the existing ones, and keeping their loads low.  I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Well we just lowered it to 48% so that it could scale up properly and not take our app down. I'm stress testing it right now with the ASG set to a max of 1 instance to get those `iostat` numbers and its still just hovering in the high 50s.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot heres a pastebin with extended iostat output - https://pastebin.com/wt4qR4UY